# Using gitlab-ci default variables in docker-compose.yaml

Tags: docker-compose, gitlab-ci

I want to tag the docker image with default git variable for branch name `CI_COMMIT_BRANCH`

But when I run the code the value of `CI_COMMIT_BRANCH` becomes an empty string and hence the docker image is tagged as `_service1` without branch name.

.gitlab-ci.yml

```
Tag Images:
  stage: push images
  script:
    - sudo docker-compose build
```

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '2.1'
services:
  service1:
    build: ./service1
    image: service1:${CI_COMMIT_BRANCH}_service1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved this by adding the variable to **.env** file dynamically

.gitlab-ci.yml

```
Tag Images:
  stage: push images
  before_script:
    - echo 'BRANCH_NAME='$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH >> .env #This command will create .env if not exists 
  script:
    - sudo docker-compose build
```

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '2.1'
services:
  service1:
    build: ./service1
    image: service1:${BRANCH_NAME}_service1
```

Comment: you want to use $CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG instead of $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH

Answer (score 0):

## Pass variables to `docker-compose`

You may:

- either pass variable with `-e`

See manual [Set environment variables](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#set-environment-variables-in-containers)

- or create `env` file containing declared variables and pass it's name with `--env-file`

See [manual](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env_file-configuration-option)

## Export variables in `.gitlab-ci.yml`

Also, you cat try to `export` variable in `before_script` block of `gitlab-ci.yml':

```
before_script:
  - export IMAGE_NAME=service1:${CI_COMMIT_BRANCH}_service1
```

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2.1'
services:
  service1:
    build: ./service1
    image: ${IMAGE_NAME}
```

Comment: I tried the suggested solution but it did not help, please suggest if anything else needs to be updated like docker-compose version.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [predefined_variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html), I don't think `CI_COMMIT_BRANCH` is the correct variable to use in your scenario, as the commit branch name is "Present only when building branches." (Which i'm guessing is the cause of the `_service1` docker image tag)

Perhaps, you could use `CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME` instead?

Comment: It is added in Gitlab version 12.6 Reference: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html

Answer (score 0):

Adding a much better answer to this question.

**Step 1: Define Variables**

In your .gitlab-ci.yml or in your GitLab project's CI/CD settings, define the variables you need.

.gitlab-ci.yml Example:

```
variables:
  MY_VARIABLE: "my_value"
```

**Step 2: Use Variables in Docker Compose**

In your docker-compose.yml, utilize environment variables.

docker-compose.yml Example:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  myservice:
   image: myimage:latest
   environment:
     MY_ENV_VARIABLE: "${MY_VARIABLE}"
```